# "Goofy ideas" of Harry Nyquist?

Tags: biographical-details, quote, engineering

I was watching this lecture series by Dr. Richard Hamming on "Learning to Learn" and in [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wO8ZHnn3Q4&index=14&list=PL2FF649D0C4407B30), he describes [Harry Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Nyquist) as

> *a great man who could do two things, you dont meet very often. He was a very nice guy, a very smart guy, but...he had his goofy ideas too!*

So, I am interested in knowing what were Nyquist's "goofy" ideas? What was he trying to solve with those ideas and How were they disproved or why were they disregarded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "goofy idea" that I could find out is that he was ahead of his time. Here sis the quote from his [biography](https://nitum.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/biography-of-harry-nyquist/):

Good old Harry Nyquist also recommended that the number of samples per second for a good representation of the signal has to be twice as big as the number of Hertz of the fastest sine wave contained in the analog signal. Since the telephone only allows 4 kHz through the phone line, sampling for voice is done 8000 times per second.

Signal Sampling Theory was an exercise in frustration for Nyquist, since it needed 30,000 samples a second to make it work, and no system at that time could measure, record, store and reread that much information that quickly. He had to wait for computers, binary language, transistors and integrated circuits – 60 years of technological progress – to make digital recording and playback a reality.